# Objectify filter on ref

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

I want have two entities

```
@Entity
public class User {
   @Index private String email;
   @Index private String name;
   @Index private String age;
     }
 @Entity
public class poll {
     @Index private String pollid;
     @Index private String answer;
     @Index private Ref<User> user;
    }
```

Now if I want to query poll and filter by email I m getting empty. Is it possible?

```
ofy().load().type(Poll.class).filter("email", email).list();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do "indirect" queries on GAE (e.g. A JOIN type queries). Basically, your "poll" entity does not have the "email" field.

Comment: So what type of structure should i have if i want to filter using email id. Will embed help?